# React Native "An unknown error occurred" by Apple review

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-iap

I use [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/) package (6.0.3)

React native version is 0.64

I get no error when testing iap in ios but Apple Review gets "An unknown error occurred" when they try to call requestPurchase method. I tested in real device and simulator, both of them have no error. I waited a day and submit again but app has been rejected again.  What can i do?

Comment: You need to be more specific and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I resolved.
Xcode > Signing Capabilities > Add > In-App Purchase and bingo Apple approved!

Comment: This seems to be something new, I had an app previously working with the service. Thanks for the tip